# Index.php deleted by accident

Tags: php, wordpress

My index.php in wordpress was replaced by another one (wrong) and I have no original backup! What should I do?

I tried to get code from oldindex.php but then get `Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/taxitaxi/public_html/index.php on line 1`.

Functions are invisible!

What should I do?

Comment: this is not a programming question. but i say get the original index.php from the tar file.

Comment: There are two types of people around: those who do backup, and those who will.

Comment: just find and download your Wordpress version and take index.php from there.

Comment: @Marcin: backup, and probably version control on top of that

Comment: First rule of running a website (or indeed, any computer system): Do your backups. Consider this an example of learning the easy way. (the hard way would have been if your data had gone missing as well)

Comment: Bit late now but you should **always** use source control on every project, even if you are the only dev! Check out `git` or `svn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all.

**Always make a backup of your wordpress theme/website** (or any other website/program)

Solution:

Download a clean and new wordpress installation from:[HERE](http://wordpress.org/download/)

Replace your corrupted/wrong `index.php` with the newly downloaded one. This should fix your problems.

Remember. **Always make backups**

Answer (score 2):

Replace it from original wordpress installation. Jus download an archived Wordpress bundle from original site and take the index.php file from that archive

Comment: Frankly, my advice would be to re-install the whole of wordpress, not just the index. He didn't say how index file had been corruped, but there's every chance that other files have also been affected.